# Dropbox LAN Sync on Android Device

Tags: sync, dropbox

Dropbox provides [LAN Sync](https://www.dropbox.com/help/137) for PCs to save time & money. Is there any way to enable it for Android devices? All Dropbox sync apps use only internet for syncing.

Comment: Good question! But I think you have to contact Dropbox directly on this topic and maybe add a feature request.

Comment: @Flow They don't provide even `sync` feature.. how can I request this feature?

Comment: You don't need a full sync for LAN sync. The Android device could pull the file in question from you local PC with a Dropbox instance running without performing a full sync. I think feature requests can only be done by paying customers, but you would post to the [forum](http://forums.dropbox.com/)

Comment: @Flow The whole point of LAN sync is to speed up normal sync. Technically, LAN sync is possible without internet sync, but how can it hold prime aim of Dropbox when files aren't uploaded to online Dropbox account.. And, what about your other devices not in LAN.. Is it really a sync? To provide LAN sync, they need to provide internet sync. LAN sync is a subset of normal Sync.

Comment: @Sachin The Dropbox app itself doesn't support syncing but you can use [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync) or another third party app for that.

Comment: @Erik Oops.. I have already mentioned that in my question.. No sync app supports `LAN Sync`…

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use both Dropbox and a LAN syncing tool like [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). I couldn't find any LAN syncing tool for Android but if you mount your device in Mass Storage Mode, running Unison purely on your PC should yield acceptable performance. It may also be possible to compile Unison on Android (it works on GNU/Linux), but that would be fairly difficult.